# SpringBoot 2 - Monitor DB connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have configured a DB Connection (HikariCP) on SprintBoot 2. 
I have the poolName defined in the **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariConnectionPool
```

I want to monitor the number of idle DB connections, so I tried to create a thread which monitors the DB connections as:

```
public class HikariCPStatistics implements Runnable {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HikariCPStatistics.class);

    private static HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy;

    public HikariCPStatistics() {
            MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            try {
                    ObjectName poolName = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (HikariConnectionPool)");
                    poolProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mBeanServer, poolName, HikariPoolMXBean.class);

            } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            logger.info("Starting Connection Pool status monitor");
            while ( true ) {
                    logger.info("Hikari - Idle Connections: " + poolProxy.getIdleConnections());
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            logger.error("Fail to run Connection Pool status monitor");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

    }
```

}

but I'm getting an exception that it's not able to find the instance of the poolName **HikariConnectionPool**.
Any suggestion on how I can get the idle DB connections managed by HikariCP?

---

further analyzes, I could see that SpringBoot is not actually registering the **Pool** bean in JMX.
SpringBoot is only publishing the **HikariDataSource** bean in JMX, which have the static configuration of Hikari dataSource.
From what I can see, Hikari supports 2 differents configuration patterns:
1) configuration though the HikariConfig class 
2) direct configuration of the HikariDataSource 
SpringBoot is using the 2nd option.
I have tried in the past the 1st option configuring HikariCP (no SpringBoot) which was registering **Pool** and **PoolConfig** Beans.... The **Pool** bean is the one which I'm interested which has the usage of the connections.

Does anybody know how I can configure as option (1 - HikariConfig class) instated HikariDataSource in SpringBoot? Or somehow springboot to create a **Pool** Bean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To get  " idle DB connections managed by HikariCP, First get the HikariPool used by [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/metadata/HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata.java)

```
HikariPool hikariPool = (HikariPool) new DirectFieldAccessor(getDataSource()).getPropertyValue("pool");
```

And then use [HikariPool](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/metadata/HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata.java) method to get current idle connections status:

```
hikariPool.getIdleConnections();
```

For initialize by HikariConfig see [Hikari's initialization](https://github.com/openbouquet/HikariCP#initialization)

> HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
>
> config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons");
>
> config.setUsername("bart");

..

> HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);

Comment: @HelioAymoto did you found the solution, did the above answer help, if yes please accept the answer so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i monitor connection pool

```
        HikariPool hikariPool = (HikariPool)
                new DirectFieldAccessor(dataSource).getPropertyValue("pool");

        //Getting pool connection info
        logger.info(" hikariPool getActiveConnections : " + hikariPool.getActiveConnections());
        logger.info(" hikariPool getTotalConnections : " + hikariPool.getTotalConnections());
        logger.info(" hikariPool getIdleConnections : " + hikariPool.getIdleConnections());
        logger.info(" hikariPool getThreadsAwaitingConnection : " + hikariPool.getThreadsAwaitingConnection());

        //Getting maximum pool size - set from properties
        Integer t= new HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata((HikariDataSource) dataSource).getMax();
        logger.info(" hikariPool Maximum Pool Size : " + t.toString());
```

Comment: hi how do u determine the pool? what is the value of  pool ? what it does .getPropertyValue("pool");

Answer (score 1):

You can get lots of info from the Hikari connection pool injecting the HikariDataSource. even as a list.

```
private final List<HikariDataSource> hikariConfigMXBeans;

infos like name = hikariDataSource.getPoolName();
idleTimeout = hikariDataSource.getIdleTimeout();
validationTimeout = hikariDataSource.getValidationTimeout();
connectionTimeout = hikariDataSource.getConnectionTimeout();
leakDetectionThreshold = hikariDataSource.getLeakDetectionThreshold();
maxLifetime = hikariDataSource.getMaxLifetime();
minimumIdle = hikariDataSource.getMinimumIdle();
maxPoolSize = hikariDataSource.getMaximumPoolSize();
```

From here is easy to create an actuator endpoint to show this info.

Hope this are the kind of info you neet to monitor

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for your answer.
The sample you write can get the static configuration of the Hikari Pool.
I'm looking for the dynamic information... in this case, the poolProxy.getIdleConnections which give the current number of available connection in the pool in idle status... so i can be monitoring at run time the application if it's consuming all  connection from the pool.

Comment: aaaa ok sry. misunderstood :)